# Java, is this a Deep copy?

Tags: java, deep-copy

I cant seem to get a clear precise answer by reading any of the similar questions, I'm trying to deep Clone an object in Java using a copy constructor is this a deep copy:

```
public class Tile{
    Image sprite = null;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    public Tile(Image setImage, int sX, int sY){
         this.sprite = setImage;
         this.x = sX;
         this.y = sY;
    }
    public Tile(Tile copyTile){
         this.sprite = copyTile.sprite;
         this.x = copyTile.x;
         this.y = copyTile.y;
    }
    public void setNewLocation(int sX, int sY){
         this.x = sX;
         this.y = sY;
    }
}
```

Then when I create my tile map I could do something like this

```
List<Tile> tileList = new List<Tile>();
Tile masterGrassTile = new Tile(grassImage, 0,0);
tileList.set(0,new Tile(masterGrassTile));
tileList.set(1,new Tile(masterGrassTile));
tileList.get(0).setNewLocation(0,32);
tileList.get(1).setNewLocation(0,64);
```

If i were to render both tiles at their respective locations would that work? or was the assignment tileList.get(1).setNewLocation(0,64); effecting like a reference and all of them have the same location as the last assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, lets review the differences between a deep and a shallow copy.

A shallow copy points to the same references as the source.  So if make a copy of instance `A` named `B` any changes to fields containing objects in `B` will modify these fields in `A` since they are pointing to the same reference.

A deep copy has independent fields/references, it does not point to the source's references.  A change to a field/property on the copy will not impact the source's fields/properties.

In your case, I believe you have made a shallow copy since your assigning the reference of sprite field from the source to the copy's sprite field.

To illustrate this, I have modified the `Tile` classes source to expose the `Image` and have mocked an `Image` class.

**Modifications for Proof of Concept**

```
class Tile{
        /* Rest of Class*/
        //Additions
    public Image getSprite() {
        return sprite;
    }
    public void setSprite(Image sprite) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
    }

}

//Mock
class Image{
    public String name;
    public Image(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Proof of Concept**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Tile> tileList = new ArrayList<Tile>();
    Tile masterGrassTile = new Tile(new Image("grass.png"), 0,0);

    Tile copyTile = new Tile(masterGrassTile);
    copyTile.getSprite().name = "water.png";

    System.out.println(masterGrassTile.getSprite().name); //Prints water.png
}
```

Notice how changing the copied instance's sprite property affects the original instances sprite property.

Comment: I've realized that its apparently a partial Copy, Image is still a reference because i'm passing an object but the int's are fully copied because they are primitives! to make it a deep copy id have to clone the image using .clone() or new Image(copyImage.sprite); so that it creates a new location in memory. Thank you for responding!

Comment: @JayPC Glad I could help some, it sounds like your right on track.  Good Question!

Answer (score 11):

> is this a deep copy ?

No, it's not because `this.sprite = copyTile.sprite;` both objects of `Tile` is refering to same object of `Image`.

> If i were to render both tiles at their respective locations would that work? or was the assignment tileList.get(1).setNewLocation(0,64); effecting like a reference and all of them have the same location as the last assignment.

No, the values of x and y are independent in the two objects of `Tiles` and code should work and both the objects will have different x and y values.

Comment: I would add that with the `int` fields you don't have that problem because they are primitive data types

Comment: Ok so Id need to do something like:
this.sprite = copyTile.sprite.copy();

Answer (score 3):

In java there are two data types:

- primitives (float, int , double, boolean ...) which doesn't have concept of deep/shallow copying because they work with assignments.
- objects where a shallow copy means passing the reference. while a deep copy means having a new object with the same values that the source has.

giving the above your code doesn't satisfy deep copying when passing the `Image` object. 
and if you are rendering using that object then that object can only have one position. which will cause your code to render both tiles at the same place.

To fix this you should clone your `Image` object.

```
 public Tile(Tile copyTile){
     this.sprite = copyTile.sprite.clone();
     this.x = copyTile.x;
     this.y = copyTile.y;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! It can be rendered multiple times so guess I don't  HAVE to fully deep copy as mentioned in other answers. but now that I know the difference Ill remember that for when i add more things to the Tile class.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not a deep copy as the same Image object is shared between all object of Tile.

Looking at your example though it appears that this copy would be sufficient for your needs as  it allows you to reuse the same Image object on different locations (which presumably is more efficient).

Comment: I realize that now thank you! Then if I change the base image it would change for all of them so good to remember.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#6

*If a method returns a reference to an internal mutable object, then client code may modify the internal state of the instance. Unless the intention is to share state, copy mutable objects and return the copy.*

So you'd have to actually make a new instance out of `Image`.

```
public Tile(Tile copyTile){
     this.sprite = new Image();
     //Then copy the image to the newly instantiated sprite
     this.x = copyTile.x;
     this.y = copyTile.y;
}
```

Comment: Right! forgot that the image would just be a reference.